# Integrate $match into aggregate query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Trying to group documents, and then limit to a date range like this:

```
db.checkins.aggregate([{
    "$group": { _id: "$movie_id", count: { "$sum": 1 } }
},
{
    "$match": { createdAt: { $gte: ISODate("2015-07-21T21:38:39.987Z"), $lte: ISODate("2015-07-28T21:38:39.987Z") }}
},
{
        "$sort": {count: -1}
}
])
```

My Collection looks like this:

```
{
    movie_id: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}
```

If I remove the `$match`, the correct data is returned, all grouped correctly. However, if I include the `$match`, no data is returned, just an empty array.

Any ideas?

(Obviously I have checked whether the data is there for those date ranges!)

Comment: It's in the wrong place. Put the `$match` first. Think unix pipe `grep | sed | awk`. That means things only flow  "into" the next pipeline stage from "output" of the previous stage.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Ace, thank you!